# Passing string from edittext to new intent gives error

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-edittext

I'm trying to pass the value of string to the next intent that I got from an EditText box.

```
final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
final String userid = et1.getText().toString();

final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final String pass = et2.getText().toString();

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        Intent i= new Intent(Main.this, Main1.class);
        i.putExtra("userid",userid);
        i.putExtra("pass",pass);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

In Main1.class I have the following code...

```
Intent i= getIntent();
String userid = i.getStringExtra("userid");
String pass = i.getStringExtra("pass");
```

But I get an error. After checking the logcat I found out that the error is in this line:

```
String userid = i.getStringExtra("userid");
```

I think I'm trying to receive the strings incorrectly though I don't know what the real problem is. Am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to send and receive Strings through intents? If there is any other way, please help me out.
Both my classes extend Activity and implement `OnClickListener`.

Comment: It looks correct. Can you post the logcat and verify that `userid` isn't `null`?

Comment: Solved it. Was trying the code at the receiving end "outside" the OnCreate method.

Answer (score 3):

do it this way

you should try to get element inside `onClickEvent`

```
final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 

final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       

        String userid = et1.getText().toString(); 
        String pass = et2.getText().toString();     

        Intent i= new Intent(Main.this, Main1.class);
        i.putExtra("userid",userid);
        i.putExtra("pass",pass);

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why? Not sure why this is getting upvoted. The way the OP is doing it is fine since the `String` is declared as `final`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I was actually trying that code outside of the OnCreate method. Silly me. I just put it inside the OnCreate method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
    'final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 

final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       

        String userid = et1.getText().toString(); 
        String pass = et2.getText().toString();     

        Intent i= new Intent(Main.this, Main1.class);
        i.putExtra("userid",userid);
        i.putExtra("pass",pass);

        startActivity(i);
    }
});'
```

And,Receive like this

```
Intent i= getIntent();
String userid = i.get("userid").toString();
String pass = i.get("pass").toString();
```

Problem is Your missing when receive string **toString()** after only you can assign